# How to Pivot Mysql data without without repeating the records. I have used group by, but I am not getting the results I want

Tags: mysql

I have this data

[image]

I want to have name,jan,feb,mar columns. i used Case to pivot like this

```
 select name,
    CASE WHEN datepaid LIKE '%-01-%' THEN amountpaid ELSE 0 END AS jan, 
    CASE WHEN datepaid LIKE '%-02-%' THEN amountpaid ELSE 0 END AS feb, 
    CASE WHEN datepaid LIKE '%-03-%' THEN amountpaid ELSE 0 END AS mar 
FROM payments;
```

[image]

I DO NOT WANT THE `NAME` to repeat.
When I group by `name` I end up with the last records of the respective names as shown

```
select name,
    CASE WHEN datepaid LIKE '%-01-%' THEN amountpaid ELSE 0 END AS jan, 
    CASE WHEN datepaid LIKE '%-02-%' THEN amountpaid ELSE 0 END AS feb, 
    CASE WHEN datepaid LIKE '%-03-%' THEN amountpaid ELSE 0 END AS mar 
FROM payments 
group by name;
```

[image]

Kindly help
Here is SQL DATA.

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `datepaid` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amountpaid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `payments` (`datepaid`, `name`, `amountpaid`) VALUES
('2020-01-13', 'james', 150),
('2020-01-14', 'mercy', 150),
('2020-01-16', 'otieno', 150),
('2020-01-17', 'njoroge', 100),
('2020-02-18', 'james', 150),
('2020-02-20', 'mercy', 150),
('2020-02-21', 'otieno', 150),
('2020-03-15', 'william', 50),
('2020-03-19', 'njoroge', 100),
('2020-03-22', 'william', 50),
('2020-03-23', 'njoroge', 100);
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Use `SUM(CASE WHEN ... END)`

Comment: Someone marked this question as a duplicate yet it was not. Thank you @Barmar. It worked

Comment: In which case it obviously is

Comment: That was me, since the duplicate should have the same solution I put in my comment.